# Store Master Page in Database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, master-pages

Using Asp.Net MVC is it possible to store a Master Page in a database so I can have different editable Master Pages for different users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question here on SO may help you out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523073/asp-net-mvc-pull-and-populate-masterpage-contents-from-database).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, If Sharepoint can do this, so can you. Take at look at this thread over at [asp.net forums](http://forums.asp.net/p/1477034/3461061.aspx)

Comment: My bad, I wasn't saying you were using Sharepoint, but the fact that Sharepoint does this which means you can too.